# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject return null for the object instead of the overflow integer itself

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have the following data object.

```
    public class myObject
        {
            public string user
            {
                get; set;
            }
    
            public List<available> available
            {
                get; set;
            }
    
        }
        public class available
        {
            public string name
            {
                get; set;
            }
            public int points
            {
                get; set;
            }
   }
```

If I use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize the following data (overflowed points)

```json
{
   "user":"12345",
   "available":[
      {
         "name":"test",
         "points":1234567891012345
      }
   ]
}
```

it returns null for available object

but if I have the following class and

```
public class available
        {
            public int points
            {
                get; set;
            }
            }
```

deserialize the following data, it returns 0 for points.

```
{
            "points": 1234567891012345,
}
```

Why did the first one returns null for the object?

Comment: Sorry for this comment, I know it is not helping with your question but at work we moved away from newtonsoft and started using Microsoft System.Text.Json

Comment: Please show your deserialization code. Also what version of Newtonsoft.Json you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, suggestion is, please improve your question so we can help you answer accurately.

Second I can see exception in this scenario from newton soft because you are using output bound value for integer.

**Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.2**

You should see an error, something like below:

````cs
Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 
JSON integer 1234567891012345 is too large or small for an Int32. 
Path 'available[0].points'```

Use a data type for your needs appropriately.
````